# Hotcakes: hide PayPal Express from Cart view if not logged in

Tags: e-commerce

In Hotcakes, is there a way to hide PayPal Express from the Cart view if the user is not logged in? In Views/Cart/Index.cshtml, I see:

```
@if (Model.PayPalExpressAvailable) {
    [PayPal Express button gets added here]
}
```

However, is there anything I can add to the logic to check for logged in status? I don't see anything in CartViewModel.

Or is there another way to achieve this?

FYI, the reason for hiding it is that if the non-registered user purchases via PayPal Express, they do not get prompted to create an account during the checkout process, so it appears it would require a support request to connect them to their order information after purchase.

We are using Hotcakes version 1.10.4 Pro.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find this already answered in a slightly different context in a previous question.

[Access Roles in DNN Hotcakes Checkout Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136270/access-roles-in-dnn-hotcakes-checkout-views)

You'll just check for `UserInfo != null` and `UserInfo.UserID > 0` in your case. In the linked answer, `UserInfo` is the `customer` object.

Comment: My pleasure! :)